# hibernate warning : fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext

Tags: hibernate, jboss5.x

Occasionally I am getting following warning in my jboss server log where my j2ee app is running for hours. After this warning we are getting NoClassDefFoundError

fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext@39eda49b
On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [6] entries

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest

After bouncing server, things are working fine for few hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you let me know the version of Hibernate you are using? This is a hibernate bug and has been fixed in version 3.2.6 and higher.

You can check it [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/181678?start=0&tstart=0) and [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=979742)